# Same Http request works on one host but not the other

Tags: php, apache, sockets, http, curl

**I have the following code:**

```
function posturl($URL, $post_data, $referrer = "") {  
        $URL_Info = parse_url ( $URL );
        // Building referrer
        if ($referrer == "")
                $referrer = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"];

        // making string from $data
        foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value )
                $values [] = "$key=" . urlencode ( $value );

        $data_string = implode ( "&", $values );

        if (! isset ( $URL_Info ["port"] ))
                $URL_Info ["port"] = 80;

        $request .= "POST " . $URL_Info ["path"] . " HTTP/1.1\n";
        $request .= "Host: " . $URL_Info ["host"] . "\n";
        $request .= "Referer: $referrer\n";
        $request .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n";
        $request .= "Content-length: " . strlen ( $data_string ) . "\n";
        $request .= "Connection: close\n";
        $request .= "\n";
        $request .= $data_string . "\n";

        echo ">>>> Request:\n";
        echo($request);
        var_dump($URL_Info);

        $fp = fsockopen ( $URL_Info ["host"], $URL_Info ["port"] );
        fputs ( $fp, $request );
        while ( ! feof ( $fp ) ) {
                $result .= fgets ( $fp, 128 );
        }
        fclose ( $fp );
        $result=substr($result, strpos($result, "\r\n\r\n"));
        return $result;
}
```

**And the following request:**

```
POST /fia/interface/product_use_action.php HTTP/1.1
Host: orlof.is
Referer: 
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 111
Connection: close

task=check&ticket_number=EDDAFIA073&secret_code=htl440&seller_number=104&ternimal_number=Edda&global_language=8
```

**I get the following response:**

https://pastebin.com/5sf4fUiY

**My question:**

Is there something wrong with the request?

Also I have the same code and the same request but different `Host`, and I don't get errors there.

```
POST /fia/interface/product_use_action.php HTTP/1.1
Host: test.orlof.is
Referer: 
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 111
Connection: close

task=check&ticket_number=EDDAFIA073&secret_code=htl440&seller_number=104&ternimal_number=Edda&global_language=8
```

As we can see the only difference is `test.orlof.is` instead of `orlof.is`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is really the problem, but there are two obviously wrong things with your request:

> ```
>     $request .= "POST " . $URL_Info ["path"] . " HTTP/1.1\n";
> ```

The end of line with HTTP should be `\r\n`, not `\n`. This is true for all line endings including the separator between HTTP header and body.

> ```
>    $request .= "Content-length: " . strlen ( $data_string ) . "\n";
>    ...
>    $request .= $data_string . "\n";
> ```

You specify the length of the body with `strlen ( $data_string )` but you actually send one byte more. There is no need to send a `\n` at the end of the body but when you do you should account for this in the `content-length` header too.

Apart from that you are doing a HTTP/1.1 request but expect that you can simply treat the HTTP response body as the final data. But, with HTTP/1.1 the server can only used chunked transfer encoding, i.e. the response will be in chunks with each chunk having a size prefix. If you don't want to deal with this better use HTTP/1.0.

As to why it works with one server and not the other: it might be because one server might have a more forgiving implementation of the HTTP standard and the other a more strict. In any case the ultimate source for how use HTTP is [the standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) and not some examples you've seen somewhere.

Comment: Ending each line be `\r\n` made the request function properly.